# how to enhance solr.StandardTokenizerFactory to produce a couple extra tokens?

Tags: solr, tokenize

I have a Solr 3.6 deployment.  Currently I'm using solr.StandardTokenizerFactory to parse tokens during indexing.

Here's two example streams that demonstrate my issue:

Example 1: `bob,a-z,000123,xyz` produces tokens ... `|bob|a-z|000123|xyz|` ... which is good.

Example 2: `bob,a-6,000123,xyz` produces tokens ... `|bob|a-6,000123|xyz|` ... which is not good because users can't search by "000123".

It seems StandardTokenizerFactory treats the "6,000" differently (like it's currency or a product number, maybe?) so it doesn't tokenize at the comma.

QUESTION: How can I enhance StandardTokenizer to do everything it's doing now plus produce a couple of additional tokens like this ...

`bob,a-6,000123,xyz` produces tokens ... `|bob|a-6,000123|xyz|a-6|000123|`

... so users can search by "000123"?

Answer (score 0):

not sure if you can do anything with StandardTokenizerFactory (well maybe creating your own version, but that seems like too much trouble).

What you can do for sure, is use a [WordDelimiterFilterFactory](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.WordDelimiterFilterFactory). If it does not emit the terms you want, play with the different params, and at last resort use the [wdftypes.txt file](https://github.com/apache/lucene-solr/blob/master/solr/core/src/test-files/solr/collection1/conf/wdftypes.txt) to make it so

Comment: So, if I add a 'filter' of type WordDeliminatorFilterFactory after my 'tokenizer' (of type StandardTokenizerFactory), will it result it more tokens?  I thought a filter could only be used to modify the tokens produced by the Tokenizer, but could not create more tokens.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: It can insert tokens at will; a filter is just a mechanism that takes tokens as input and has tokens as it output (as TokenStreams). There is no limitation that the number of tokens outputted is the same as inputted, and many filters change the number of tokens ouput (such as all the ngram filters (which produces as token for each variation of length of the original token) or delimiter filters).

Comment: @MatsLindh Thanks.  Is there a filter I can append to StandardTokenizer that will check the outputted token(s) for a comma, and create additional tokens split at the comma?  Ideally StandardTokenizer plus that functionality would be ideal as I don't want to break anything StandardTokenizer is currently doing.

Comment: yes there is, as I suggested in my answer: WordDelimiterFilterFactory

Comment: @Persimmonium Thanks!  From the example at the link you provided, I assumed that WordDelimiterFilterFactory worked specifically with WhitespaceTokenizerFactory.  I didn't realize WordDelimiterFilterFactory could also work with StandardTokenizerFactory.  I will try it, thanks!